# Structures present in liquid water

Tags: water, intermolecular-forces, phase

I know this may be a too generic question, but here it goes anyway.

It is already know that solid water (ice) organizes its molecules in a lattice (in a variety of 16 different crystals and one amorphous phase). See, for instance, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ice .

Now, what about liquid water? Is it the case that there are a (limited) number of local structures, like stable clusters or lattices configurations, combining and dissociating over relatively short periods of time, that dominate the liquid phase, loosely resembling the organization of a solid phase (the principal difference being that the hydrogen bonds would be weaker and would break more easily because of thermal agitation)? If so, what are those frequent structures?

Comment: Do You want to know whether textbooks say the truth? What else is the aim of your question?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there are various water clusters leading to local order on the scale of a few molecules holding stabilized orientation with one another for measurable timescales.  [This article](http://www.pnas.org/content/98/19/10533.full.pdf)(1) is a pretty good introduction to the major varieties in liquid water.  [This article](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1521-3773(20010518)40:10%3C1808::AID-ANIE1808%3E3.0.CO;2-1/full)(2) talks more about various structures available in any phase, including the ices, which gives some pretty good context.

(1) Keutsch, Frank N., Saykally, Richard J., Water clusters: Untangling the mysteries of the liquid, one molecule at a time, 2001, PNAS, 98, 19, 10533–10540, doi:10.1073/pnas.191266498

(2) Ludwig, Ralf, Water: From Clusters to the Bulk, 2001, Angewandte Chemie International Edition, 40, 10, 1808-1827, doi:10.1002/1521-3773(20010518)40:10<1808::AID-ANIE1808>3.0.CO;2-1

Answer (score -2):

There is no lattice or psuedo-lattice structure associated with water while it is the liquid state. Look at it as a medley of H2O molecules combining, breaking apart, and recombining with Hydrogen bonds as the main mediator of attraction.

[image: Water Molecules and Their Interaction Amongst Each Other]

Polar molecules (like the above water molecules) have a weak, partial negative charge at one region of the molecule (the O atm) and a partial positive charge elsewhere (The H atm) These bonds that form between water molecules account for some of the unique characteristics of water.

Comment: You are correct that there is no lattice present in liquid water - but this does not mean that there can not be localised structures -and indeed there are...